# AWS Lambda python custom response encoding

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto

When you query data with your lambda function from dynamodb and there are binary types or decimal/number types in it my default setup below prompts with an JSONEncoding Error that he cannot deal with Binary or Decimal. I can work around with a small piece of code that I attach to `json.dumps(data, indent=2, cls=JSONEncoder)`

```py
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

But using `json.dumps()` in front of your `return` statement double json format the response and that leads to escaped signs. To repeat the problem just `return data` prompts with the mentioned error.

How can I affect my `return` statement that converts to json?

### UPDATE:

The problem is solved dirty by manually change the items with:

```
test = operations['Items'][0]
test['id'] = float(test['id'])
```

But this seems messy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are looking to return from the lambda handler function. If so, while not elegant, you can do this:

```
json.loads(json.dumps(value, cls=JSONEncoder))
```

Not awesome because eventually Lambda will convert that structure back into a string (not sure if there's a way to just skip the intermediate step of converting to a python structure).

Comment: why is this downvoted? In fact, this seems to be the only way to go. puzzling.